# an [advanced-programming] question

Tags: discussion, tags

Strolling around the tags page, I found [advanced-programming](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advanced-programming). It has one question, from our earliest days:

[What are good projects for metaprogramming?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/447/what-are-good-projects-for-metaprogramming)

I might be misunderstanding things, but the tag adds nothing to the question, and isn't related (as far as I can see).

So, I ask you: Is this tag useful (at this time), considering there's 1 question tagged with it? I ask this because I am not sure whether the tag is needed **on that question**, but I really don't know much about what the question asks, so I can't judge.

If it is indeed unneeded, then I suppose this is a lame [burnination-request](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burnination-request)...

UPDATE: that's been taken care of, thanks to [Buffy](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/users/1293/buffy).